# How to get 'this' var outside JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to get var with name `rate_value` outside `#rate_country`. So in `#ch_rate` function this var should have the same value.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64hzstuk/)

How I can do it?

```
<script>
var rate_default = 50;
var rate_value = ''; // this doesn't work

$('#rate_country').change(function(){
  var rate_input = $('#ch_rate').val();
  var rate_country = $(this).val();
  if (rate_country == 'AD') {
    var rate_value = rate_default * 2;
    if (rate_value > rate_input) {
      $('#rate_validity').addClass('validity_w');
      $('#ch_rate').addClass('i_wrong')
    } else {
      $('#rate_validity').removeClass('validity_w');
      $('#ch_rate').removeClass('i_wrong')
    }
  } else if (rate_country == 'AG') {
    var rate_value = rate_default * 5;
  }
});

// so the rate_value should be 250 if rate_country == AG or 100 if rate_country == AD

$('#ch_rate').keyup(function(){
  let $this = $(this);
  var rate_input = $(this).val();
  var rate_regexp = /^((0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?)?$/;
  if (rate_value > rate_input || !rate_regexp.test(rate_input)) {
    $('#rate_validity').addClass('validity_w');
    $('#ch_rate').addClass('i_wrong')
  } else {
    $('#rate_validity').removeClass('validity_w');
    $('#ch_rate').removeClass('i_wrong')
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just define `var rate_value ='';` out side the listener event and assign that value inside listener .

Comment: Yes,you are correct

Comment: @Shree Doesn't work if you create this var outside function. Check the code again.

Comment: There you go [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/64hzstuk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare rate_value once globally with `var rate_value` then refer to it as `rate_value`.  If you use `var rate_value` again it will override.

```
var rate_default = 50;
var rate_value = ''; // Define rate_value once here

$('#rate_country').change(function(){
    var rate_input = $('#ch_rate').val();
    var rate_country = $(this).val();
    if (rate_country == 'AD') {
        rate_value = rate_default * 2;  //DO NOT USE var here, just change the value of rate_value
        if (rate_value > rate_input) {
          $('#rate_validity').addClass('validity_w');
          $('#ch_rate').addClass('i_wrong')
        } else {
          $('#rate_validity').removeClass('validity_w');
          $('#ch_rate').removeClass('i_wrong')
        }
    } else if (rate_country == 'AG') {
        rate_value = rate_default * 5;  //DO NOT USE var here, just change the value of rate_value
    }

    console.log("rate_value is now: " + rate_value);  //See what rate_value is now
});

// so the rate_value  should be rate_default * 5 if rate_country == AG

$('#ch_rate').keyup(function(){
    console.log("rate_value is now: " + rate_value);  //See what rate_value is now

    let $this = $(this);
    var rate_input = $(this).val();
    var rate_regexp = /^((0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?)?$/;

    if (rate_value > rate_input || !rate_regexp.test(rate_input)) {
        $('#rate_validity').addClass('validity_w');
        $('#ch_rate').addClass('i_wrong')
    } else {
        $('#rate_validity').removeClass('validity_w');
        $('#ch_rate').removeClass('i_wrong')
    }
});
```

Remember, `var` defines the variable and sets the initial value.  Every time you use var it resets the value so only use `var` once (unless you really want to reset.)

Comment: This was my point, I want to overwrite it because If user for example selected different option from `rate_country`, then also the `rate_value` will be different.

Comment: Have a look, make sure to open your console to see the console.log messages that have been added: https://jsfiddle.net/jreljac/64hzstuk/7/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global variable or used hidden param and after you can fetch another function